# How to get the integer positions of the True entries in a pandas indexer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to get the integer positions of rows in a pandas series, where the series contains specific values, or for the positions in an boolean indexer, where the value is True.

If I have the following dataframe, I would like to get the integer positions of the `True` values in column `label`:

```
import pandas as pd
data=dict()
data["col_0"]=[-0.2518508748588564, -0.6339192005025384, -0.6938892242609978, 2.4470042529183402, 0.8977665869071174]
data["label"]=[False, False, True, False, True]
df2= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I could of course do that like below, but it seems a big awkward to me and I wonder, if there is a cleaner way to do this (especially without a reset_index, but the solution should work no matter what index labels are used in the original dataframe):

```
ser= df2['label']
new_ser= ser.reset_index(drop=True)
new_ser.index[new_ser].to_list()
```

The result is of course `[2, 4]`.

Comment: did this work for you? Kindly upvote and accept as solution if helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it was not quite, what I was looking for. It returns the index I guess, not the integer positions. For using the index, I already had a solution, as you can see above.

Comment: please see my updated answer.

Comment: no problem. Did a little bit of research this time around as I had a similar inquiry a few weeks ago. I think this is the best option for this problem. I wouldn't be surprised if `numpy` has 3 different ways to do this... so many `numpy` methods out there. Too many to learn.

Comment: The reason, why I wanted to have integer positions, is that if you use the dataframe for machine learning and have to translate it to a numpy object or a model specific darta object, you can't use the index values.

Comment: I just realized part of my answer got deleted somehow, so I have updated. You can also use: `[*np.flatnonzero(df2['label'])]` to return a list. You probably already know how to send a numpy array to a list but for completion I have updated. Have a good day.
    `Out[2]: [2, 4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
np.flatnonzero(df2['label'])
```

---

```
data=dict()
data["col_0"]=[-0.2518508748588564, -0.6339192005025384, -0.6938892242609978, 2.4470042529183402, 0.8977665869071174]
data["label"]=[False, False, True, False, True]
df2= pd.DataFrame(data)
np.flatnonzero(df2['label'])

Out[1]: array([2, 4], dtype=int64)
```

That makes it an np.array. To make a list, use:

```
[*np.flatnonzero(df2['label'])]
Out[2]: [2, 4]
```